# Display and image inside a text

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an image like this:

[image: background]

<s>I would like to display transparent letters and fill everything to look something like this:</s>

**UPDATE:** I would like to display a text with an image one it, that would look like this:

[image: 404 img]

How can I accomplish that using **CSS**? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: take a look at `background-clip` , try something to use it and tell us where you fail if you do ...(`blend-mode` was a work around for FF, but it understands `background-clip:text` now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css background-clip property.

Example code:

```css
h1 {
    color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqRWG.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>404</h1>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

you should experiment with css "mix-blend-mode"

In your case css will look like:

```
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
```

You can check the demo:

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqRWG.jpg')
}
p{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>404</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) for this kind of styling:

> **text**
>
> The background is painted within (clipped to) the foreground text.

background-clip among flex and calc can do a simple 404 error page:

```css
h1 {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqRWG.jpg) center;
  color:transparent;
  background-clip:text;
  /* makup for a basic 404 page */
  font-size:calc(15vh + 15vw);
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
* {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>404</h1>
```